# Loading a URL to an Android WebView through another app/service

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to load a URL to an Android WebView inside one app through another app? I want the second app to act as a kind of proxy and fetch the URL on behalf of the first app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Sir, possible!

Send data from your first application to the second application. Check first that user have second application installed, if second application is installed. If it's not then point the user to install it first.

```
       try {
       String a = "secondapp://?q=data";
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
       .parse(data));
       startActivity(intent);
       } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
      .parse("market://details?id=com.secondapp"));
     startActivity(intent);
     }
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html